Assign a specific color to the results in the QGIS graphical modeler
During the photovoltaic analysis using QGIS and the graphical modeler, the results are saved as shapefiles in a specific folder.
It is possible to assign a specific color to each shapefile within the modeler. For instance, lakes could be blue and forests could be green. Since the SHP are generated outside of a project I am afraid this is no possible.


You want to add the shapefile to the map with a defined color?

@BERA Yes but I do not want to do this by hand every single time, but the import in the project should happen with a assigned color

You can create style files in advance and apply them using Set Layer Style:


